# LINQ Entity Framework sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, database, linq, textbox, entity

i have a database table that looks like this :

[image]

i am trying to retrieve the textboxValue with reference to the textboxID like this :

```
   public string GetPuzzle(string tid)
   {
       return context.crosswords.First(c => c.TextBoxID == tid).TextBoxValue;
   }
```

The above code ( CRUD class file ) gave me an error : **System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements**

I have 100 text boxes created in a panel using 2 for loops , each text box have an id from 00-99 , so i am trying to append the textBoxValue to the text of the textboxes in the loop with reference to the textBoxID as the database above.

And the below code is how i try to do it , don't know if it is the correct way :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {           
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {                
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.MaxLength = (1);
            tb.Width = Unit.Pixel(40);
            tb.Height = Unit.Pixel(40);
            tb.ID = i.ToString() + j.ToString(); // giving each textbox a different id  00-99 
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tb);
            tb.Enabled = false;

            tb.Text = daoCrossword.GetPuzzle(tb.ID).ToString();
        } 

        Literal lc = new Literal();
        lc.Text = "<br />";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lc);
    }
}
```

i am trying to select textboxvalue where textboxid = tid . tid will be my tb.ID in code behind and since there is 100 loops , every time tb.ID will increase from 00-99 , so when it reach an ID that contains a value in database , it will append the textboxvalue ( from database) to that textbox and so on .

Answer (score 4):

That error is thrown when no elements are returned from your query. You are asking for `.TextBoxValue` on nothing. Consider using `.FirstOrDefault()` by itself, and checking for `null`, such as:

```
var crossword = context.crosswords.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TextBoxID == tid);

if (crossword != null) {
    crossword.TextBoxValue;
}
else {
    // error.. not found
}
```

Chances are your loop is resulting in an "off by one" error.

Comment: i am trying to select textboxvalue where textboxid = tid . tid will be my tb.ID in code behind and since there is 100 loops , every time tb.ID will increase from 00-99 , so when it reach an ID that contains a value in database , it will append the text to that textbox , thats wad i am trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an error in your algorithm for declaring ids. The Linq query is failing because it's being passed an invalid id

I would inspect the id that causes the exception.

Comment: i am trying to create a 10x10 textboxes layout

Comment: For which Id does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using 2 for-loops to create IDs for `TextBox`, each one has an id from 00 to 99

but actually TextBoxID  column values are like 0,1,2,3,4,5.

the generated IDs are not in textboxid column.

so this code:

```
return context.crosswords.First(c => c.TextBoxID == tid).TextBoxValue;
```

error

Comment: i stored the values in database using the same loop too , it just take away the 0 infront .

Comment: this error reason is you textboxid not in table,and you use first() menthod,so throw execption.

Comment: i am new to ef linq entities , i duno what is the correct way to do it and how

Comment: i have tried   return context.crosswords.Where(c => c.TextBoxID == tid).Select(i =>i.TextBoxValue).ToString(); . but it returns System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[System.String]

Comment: because you want get one of element,so you should not use where,becanse it's return list object.

Comment: you should use first or firstordefault()  first menthod http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.linq.queryable.firstordefault.aspx

Comment: basically i am trying to do this sql statement , Select TextBoxValue where TextBoxID == tid

Comment: i did tried it   return context.crosswords.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TextBoxID == tid).TextBoxValue; , it returns null ..

Comment: if you sure your textbox id value all in tables ,you can use first() method,but now,textbox id value not all in tables,.

Comment: so you use firstordefault() menthod.                                     such as:

var crossword = context.crosswords.FirstOrDefault(c => c.TextBoxID == tid);

if (crossword != null) {
    crossword.TextBoxValue;
}
else {
    // error.. not found
}

Comment: oh so u meant , if there is no textbox id value , it will return error?

Comment: oh,yes ,You finally understand.   it willreturn error because you used first()method , first() method if not find element,then throw exception.